# hide and show a table row..onclick works only for one row and then stops showing the rest

Tags: javascript, onclick

i have a javascript function who's task is to show the hidden rows of a table
javascript function:

```
function blabla(count){
 count++;  var id="ph"+count; 
 document.getElementById(id).style.display=""; 
}
```

Then i have a table in the same document with a button on the 1st row which triggers onclick event:

```
<script to declare globale variable count=1/>
<table>
 <tr id="ph1"><td>haha:<button onClick="blabla(count)"><button></td></tr>
 <tr id="ph2" style="display:none"><td>hoho</td></tr>
 <tr id="ph3" style="display:none"><td>hihi</td></tr>
</table>
```

when the page is loaded and i click on the button one time:the second row is shown..but when i click on it the second time..the third row is Not displayed...
Why is that?
anyone can help me out?

Comment: Could you show the html part with the onclick handler and the tr elements as well? Also, be sure to use the "code sample" button (101 010) at the top of the question window to lay out your code in a readable way.

Comment: <table>
 <tr id="ph1"><td>haha:</td><td><input type="file" id="w"/></td><td><img src="Style/Images/plus.jpg" onClick="blabla(count)"/></td></tr>
 <tr id="ph2" style="display:none"><td>hoho:</td><td><input type="file" id="1"/></td></tr>
 <tr id="ph3" style="display:none"><td>hihi:</td><td><input type="file" id="2"/></td></tr>
</table>

Comment: Thanks! :)
However, a better way to show the code might be to use the "edit" link below your original post. There, you can insert your code and use the "code sample" button to lay out your code in a nice gray box, like the people below have done. This will make it (a lot) easier to read.

Comment: thank you...:)..i am new here...can you find a solution?

Comment: Sure, have a look at my answer below. I saw you saying that you already have a global variable in your code; in that case the main thing that causes your code not to work as expected is that you shouldn't include the variable in your function call. So define the function as function blabla() and call it using onclick="blabla();" and you'll be ready for the next challenge, which will probably be "what happens when there are no more tr elements?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the variable "count" disappears as soon as the function call ends, so you end up showing the same table row every time. You could try moving the variable to global scope:

```
var count = 1;
function blabla() {
    count++;
    var id="ph"+count;
    document.getElementById(id).style.display="";
}
```

Based on your html, you could then change it like this:

```
<table> 
    <tr id="ph1">
        <td>haha:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="w"/></td>
        <td><img src="Style/Images/plus.jpg" onClick="blabla()"/></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr id="ph2" style="display:none">
        <td>hoho:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="1"/></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr id="ph3" style="display:none">
        <td>hihi:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="2"/></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

So, just remove the count from the function call.

However, you will encounter an error when you keep pressing the button (when you run out of elements with ids starting with "ph"). If you don't want this to happen, do something like this:

```
var count = 2;
function blabla() {
    var element = document.getElementById("ph" + count);
    if (!element) {
        alert('No more rows!');
    } else {
        element.style.display = "";
        count++;
    }
}
```

Finally, this could be done more robustly using something like jQuery, but I try to stay as close to your original code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
function blabla(count)
{
   count++; // why using this code? remove this code.
   var id="ph"+count; document.getElementById(id).style.display=""; 
}
```

try without `count++` code.

For global count use:

```
var count = 0;
function blabla()
{
   var id="ph"+count; document.getElementById(id).style.display=""; 
   count++; // this will provide you to show next row for another click.
}
```

Comment: i have count++ because..i have a global variable in my html page...and this global variable has to increment each time the button is clicked..to fetch the following rows with id=ph2,ph3

Comment: @welou your function has a count parameter, if you want to using global variable, i just change my answer, i hope it will help you.

Comment: yea;)...i used global variables and it worked...but i am also trying with jquery...from the code above given by timothy ruhle...but its not working:(